# Jquery document ready not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, document-ready

I tried many syntax from answers in questions like this but nothing work with me

document.ready the jquery function not working with wordpress

```
<script>
// normal console.log working
console.log("working");
// this not working
$( function () {
     console.log("not working");
});
// also This not working
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
     console.log("not working");
});

</script>
```

Comment: What do you see in console?

Comment: only  Working  word

Comment: can you confirm from console and network that JQuery is loaded successfully?

Comment: $(function() { console.log("this has jquery"); }); this has jquery

Comment: Check for `$ not a function` errors in the console to make sure jQuery is loaded.

Comment: it's loaded successfully . there is no errors in the console

Comment: So problem solved?

Comment: no ready function still not working

Comment: this is the jquery version included http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: write this in console and enter and see output: `typeof $`

Comment: Also make sure you've enabled the logging for errors in console.

Comment: It's working here : https://jsfiddle.net/vtofttdv/

Comment: this about wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('jQuery test');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:

```
<script>
// normal console.log working
console.log("working");
// this not working
$( function () {
     console.log("not working");
});
// also This not working
jQuery(document).ready(
  function(){
     console.log("not working");
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line at the beginning of the code:

```
$ = jQuery;
```

And then keep using `$` instead of `jQuery`.